# Where rational functions are undefined

Tags: continuity, rational-functions

I have another question/comment I'd like a fresh pair of eyes on

The question is "A rational function can have infinitely many x-values at which it is not continuous"

I know since Q(x) in the rational function P(x)/Q(x) can only be factored so many n-th amount of time depending on the degree of Q(x), the statement above is false.

But what about 1/tan(x). Isn't tan(x) undefined at all x-values that are multiple integers of 2(pi) (i.e. x cannot equal 2pi(n))? 
Do I not assume it's all integers n? In other words, do I just assume that the 1/tan(x) has constraints from [0,2pi)? Hence, excluding the integer n.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1/\tan x$ is not a rational function.

Comment: A rational function is defined as a quotient of two polynomials.  Polynomials have finitely many roots.

Comment: Aww I forgot about that basic definition >_< Thanks!

Comment: By the way, $\tan(2k\pi)$ is defined for any integer $k$. Its value is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rational function is a quotient of polynomials in which the denominator is not identically zero, i.e. of the form $$R(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)},$$ $Q \neq 0$. The points at which $R$ is undefined are precisely the zeroes of $Q$. As $Q$ is a polynomial, is has at most $\deg Q$ zeroes.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about it being a polynomial >_<

Comment: A ratio of polynomials *in which the denominator is not identically zero*. Otherwise 1/0 would be a rational function...

Comment: @CarlMummert: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow polynomials of more than one variable, then it is possible for your function to have more than one root; example:

$P(x,y)= \frac {xy-1}{x^2+y^2-1}$

will be discontinuous everywhere in the unit circle centered at the origin.

Another example, without polynomials. Let $A \subset \mathbb R$ be a connected subset:

$f(x)= \frac {2}{d(x,A)} $ , where $d(x,A):=inf $ {$d(x,a): a $ in $A$} will have uncountably-many zeros (actually, the subset A will be its zero set).

Comment: Wasn't looking for something this far away from "simple" calculus, but it's cool. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I like to throw in different stuff for that reason; glad you like it.